# Using odeint function definition

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Pretty noob question so please bear with me.

I am following the example given here-->
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268589/odeint-v2-Solving-ordinary-differential-equations

In particular, I am looking at this function:

```
void lorenz( state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t )
{                                                         
dxdt[0] = sigma * ( x[1] - x[0] );
dxdt[1] = R * x[0] - x[1] - x[0] * x[2];
dxdt[2] = x[0]*x[1] - b * x[2];
 }
```

In my case, R takes on a series of values (vector with 100 doubles).

odeint is called as:

```
integrate_const( runge_kutta4< state_type >() , lorenz , x , 0.0 , 10.0 , dt );
```

I would like to do this for each value of R. How can I accomplish this? My knowledge of C++/OOP is limited, but I am willing to learn.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "class" version, but modify it so that it is initialized with the `R` value of interest to you.

```
class lorenz_class {
    double R_;
public:
    lorenz_class (double r) : R_(r) {}
    void operator()( state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ) {
        dxdt[0] = sigma * ( x[1] - x[0] );
        dxdt[1] = R_ * x[0] - x[1] - x[0] * x[2];
        dxdt[2] = x[0]*x[1] - b * x[2];
    }
};
```

Then, iterate over your vector `R` and pass in the value to the `lorenz_class` instance that you pass to the `integrate_const` template function.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < myR.size(); ++i) {
    lorenz_class lorenz(myR[i]);
    integrate_const( runge_kutta4< state_type >() , lorenz , x , 0.0 , 10.0 , dt );
}
```

Comment: Is it o.k to use class instead of struct? Would you recommend keeping operator() private? Is it necessary/useful to do so?

Comment: @AntillarMaximus: The `operator ()` should be public so that `integrate_const` can invoke it (or you would have to make `integrate_const` a friend). I changed the answer making it a `class` instead of a `struct`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Am I correct in assuming that :R_(r){} is an initialization list called after the constructor? I am new to C++ so could you kindly explain a bit more? Ultimately, I have a 16 variable coupled Diff-Eq I will be solving. Should I be using this example or would you suggest a better way to organize it?

Comment: @AntillarMaximus: Yes, that is an initializer list. The constructor takes a double parameter, and that value is used to initialize `R_`. I am not really a numerical computing guy, so I can't say this is the best way to solve your diff-eq problem. But, it does accomplish the software problem you posed in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Just a little side note: The tutorial shows a very similar example of a parameter study of the Lorenz system: http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial.html. It is in the Thrust and the VexCL section and it shows how you can parallelize this problem to work on multiple CPUs or the GPU.

Comment: I also have a question about the streaming observer. Thus far, I have been compiling the source, once that is done, opening up a command prompt and piping the output to a text file. Is there a way to make the observer write to a file instead of the console? Also, how can I tap into runge_kutta4?

Comment: Sure, this is easy:  

    struct streaming_observer
    {
      std::ostream &out_;
      streaming_observer( std::ostream &out ) : out_( out ) { }
      void operator()( const state_type &x , time_type t )
      {
        out_ << t << "\t" << x[0] << "\t" << x[1] << "\t" << x[2] << "\n";
      }
    };

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted code. I think it is not possible to insert code into comments. Can you ask a new question instead? What do you mean by tap into runge_kutta4?

Comment: Posted here-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150160/odeint-streaming-observer-and-related-questions